# Is Universal Windows Platform required to use the Windows.Devices.Bluetooth namespace?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am evaluating the feasibility of using Bluetooth Low Energy API from windows for an existing WPF application.

I noticed that UWP is mentioned all over the place in the documentation for the `Windows.Devices.Bluetooth` namespace.  I tried creating a .NET console application but couldn't figure out how to bring this library in.

If I create a UWP console application and fix the version to 1803 for both min and max, then I CAN use this namespace without hiccup.

I want to know if UWP is required to use this namespace or not.  In the event that UWP is required, my plan B was to interface with low-energy bluetooth devices in some other way, but I can't seem to find libraries on NuGet that aren't UWP either.  Are there alternatives?  Our end users are on Windows 10 tablets, but our existing application is WPF.

Comment: No, you do not need to switch to UWP. You have to use WinRT in your WPF application to get access to BLE features. Or you can use [Bluetooth Framework](https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm). It supports WPF and provides all BLE features available on Windows platfoirms.

Answer (score 3):

***[Updated on 2018/11/16]***

Thanks @Adam Braden - MSFT for improving my reply. Yes, you could call `Windows.Devices.Bluetooth` APIs from your desktop app.

You need to add reference to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`.

Please see this blog [Calling Windows 10 APIs From a Desktop Application](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#8ZHWGWDkBfR7JgpZ.97) for more information.

Please note that If you want to call UWP APIs from desktop app, you first need to confirm if it's supported in classic desktop app. See [UWP APIs callable from a classic desktop app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/apiindex/uwp-apis-callable-from-a-classic-desktop-app) to learn how to determine if the API is available in desktop app.

Comment: To summarize, yes you can use the Windows.Devices.Bluetooth apis in a Winforms or WPF app.  VS doesn't make this easy, you need to add the reference to Windows.WinMD which is the metadata for calling Windows APIs.  To support Async() calls and a few other types required for interop, you also need to add a reference to System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll.  The articles referenced above go into more detail.

Comment: I'm getting PlatformNotSupported exceptions for certain calls in this namespace preventing me from moving forward.  It is complaining that WinRT is not supported on the platform.

Answer (score 2):

With .Net 5, Microsoft removed built-in support for the consumption of WinRT API's:

> Previously, CoreCLR could consume Windows metadata (WinMD) files to active and consume WinRT types. Starting in .NET 5, CoreCLR can no longer consume WinMD files directly.
>
> If you attempt to reference an unsupported assembly, you'll get a FileNotFoundException. If you activate a WinRT class, you'll get a PlatformNotSupportedException.

However, there is a recommended solution and that is to change the target framework moniker (TFM). For example, in your project file (assuming you are targeting .Net 5):

```
<!-- Change from -->

<TargetFramework>net5</TargetFramework>

<!-- To -->    

<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041</TargetFramework>
```

This will provide access to the API's (although there are still some exceptions to specific API's).

At the time of writing this, the available TFM's are:

> Replace the value of the TargetFramework element with one of the following strings:
>
> - net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0: Use this value if your app targets Windows 10,  version 1809.
> - net5.0-windows10.0.18362.0: Use this value if your app targets Windows 10, version 1903.
> - net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0: Use this value if your app targets Windows 10, version 2004.

For more information, you can see the [Built-in support for WinRT is removed from .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/interop/5.0/built-in-support-for-winrt-removed) web page from Microsoft and for a detailed description on what options are available, see the [Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance) web page.